# Background width not 100% on window resize or mobile units

Tags: html, css

I'm having some troubles with making 2 divs 100% width even on mobile units and on windows resize. Currently it just cuts off and that doesn't look good.

[Click here](http://necgaming.com/axy/index_guest.php) for a live preview of the site.

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    margin: auto;
    width: 1170px;
}

#helper {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   min-width: 1024px;
   height: 250px;
}


#header {
    background-image: url("space.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    animation: animatedBackground 35s linear infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#menu {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9cccd;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 -20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="helper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="wrap">
            <a href=""><img src="neclogo.png" alt="" style="margin-top: 80px;" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="logotype" class="steam" data-tip="NecGaming on Steam"><a href="#" class="steam-popup"><i class="fa fa-steam" style="padding:0"></i></a></div>
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-users"></i><a href="#">Members</a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-server"></i><a href="#">Servers</a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">Ranking</a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-money"></i><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-question"></i><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul> 

            <a href="#signup" rel="signup"><div id="register">Register</div></a>
            <a href="#signin" rel="signin"><div id="login">Sign In</div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How it's cut off after you resize the window to a smaller size and scroll to the right:
[image]

I just want to know how I'd make the backgrounds "repeat"/be at 100% width no matter what, even on windows resize and mobile units (phones/tablets).

Comment: You might want to implement "responsive design" with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) useful. But for starters, try removing the fixed width & min-width properties.

Comment: Removing the widths and min-widths doesn't solve the problem really, can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean, if you don't know about responsive design and media queries, you should definitely read about them. Basically, media queries allow you to define different CSS rules based on the screen size.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, will look it up for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Remove min-width, that should do it.

Comment: No effect, unfortunately.

Comment: So you removed the 'min-width' attributes and refreshed the page and it didn't work?
Can you try to clear browser's cache? And then refresh.

Comment: I'm working on my localhost with the changes, yes I removed them.

Comment: Found it. So if you remove the min-width attributes and then set the width of the 'wrap' class to 100%, it would not cut-off the elements.
Or if you don't want it to be 100%, set it to some other value but in % and not in pixels.

Comment: Updated, as per request

Comment: @P.Nick It's still the same css.